# Can't return records in Crystal using Crystal Report Date Range and an Oracle DateTime field

Tags: oracle, plsql, crystal-reports

I may be going about this all wrong, which is why I am reaching out. I have a Crystal Report that uses an Oracle database as a source of data. I wrote a command to grab the needed records from the database. Then I am using two Crystal Report Date parameters to create a range. The date that I am checking for existence within the range in my Record Selection is an Oracle date, which is showing up as a date time. I have tried using CDate, CStr, and Date but I cannot get data to display. Now if I remove the parameters, I can see data. But they need to be able to use the range. Is this "truly" possible??

Comment: Please show relevant code, or something.

Comment: Well I was wondering if it was even possible, but my original formula from my selection expert was `CDate ({Command.B1_FILE_DD(1)}) in {?ReportFrom} to {?ReportTo}` where Command.B1_FILE_DD(1) is the Oracle date field and the other two field are the Crystal Report Date parameters. This returned 0 rows.

Comment: Then I tried `CDate(CStr({Command.B1_FILE_DD(1)}, 'MM-DD-YYYY')) in {?ReportFrom} to {?ReportTo}` and this gave me the error Bad Date Format String.